# how to avoid headers repeating everytime I append in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im trying to append values from stored values taken from users. Is there a way to hard code the headers ("Player Name", "Age" and "Number") so evertime I run the code these headers dont appear again in the csv.

Edit: I want the headers to appear the "First time" it runs and not the ones after

```
data = {'Player Name': [playersNames[0]],
        'Age': [Age[0]],
        'Number': [number],

        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df.to_csv("Info.csv",mode='a',index=False, header=True)
        print(df)
```

At the moment it does this:

```
Player Name,Age,Number
x,15,73
Player Name,Age,Number
y,25,70
```

Comment: this code is inside a loop or method of some sort right? The "first time" you do this you want what you have, the next you want `header=False`

Comment: @JonSG no its not in a loop, when I say `header=False` the headers dont appear.

Comment: Without knowing more about how this is called it is hard to say. I guess conceptually test if the file exists. if it does do not write the headers if is does not then write the headers. `header = not os.path.isfile("Info.csv")` maybe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
import pathlib

csvfile = pathlib.Path('Info.csv')
df.to_csv(csvfile, mode='a', index=False, header=not csvfile.exists())
```

Comment: This is clever. You can also use the index if you track one in a loop `header=ind == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the header to be appended as well, then set `headers=False` in your call to `to_csv`.

In this situation, if you are running the script multiple times but only want headers appended on the first execution, then you could check if the file exists.

```py
import os
exists = os.path.exists('Info.csv')
```

Then, set `headers=not exists` when calling `to_csv`.

Docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Comment: I want the headers to appear the "first time", but not the rest of the time, how could I do this?

Comment: Are you running the script multiple times?

Comment: yea, but it's not in a loop. So everytime I run the script, I want it to add the player names, ages, etc to 1 csv file

Comment: Edited my answer. @Corralien's response might be more idiomatic.